# Não consigo pegar o valor do id do usuário

Tags: php

Preciso pegar o valor do id do usuário e selecionar no banco de dados os registros desse id.

Link

```
<a href="https://xxx/agendar.php?usuario=07b83439f6b5b7bc2f97905c8f2b208bf08a68fb&amp;senha=adcd7048512e64b48da55b027577886ee5a36350&amp;idbgta=2510" target="_blank" tabindex="-1" rel="external">Clique aqui para ver suas consultas</a>
```

Aqui pego o valor do id do usuário:

```
$criptoNomeUsuario = $_GET["usuario"];
$criptoSenha = $_GET["senha"];


$confirmacao = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE userlogin = '$criptoNomeUsuario' and passlogin = '$criptoSenha' and ativo = 'sim' and nivel = 'paciente'";


$result_confirmacao = mysqli_query($conn, $confirmacao);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result_confirmacao) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_confirmacao)) {


        $atendente_paciente = $row["atendente"];
        $id_usuarioeee = $row["id_usuario"];

        $nome_pacientew = $row["nome"];

        echo    "Atendente: ".$atendente_paciente;      

    }
} else {

}
```

Resultado

```
Atendente: 2
```

Agora que vem o problema:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$start = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET["start"]);
$end = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET["end"]);

$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT `id`, `start` ,`end` ,`title`,`ativo`,`atendente` FROM  `events` where (date(start) >= '$start' AND date(start) <= '$end' AND ativo='sim' and atendente='".$atendente_paciente.
    "'   ) ");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $events[] = $row;

}


echo json_encode($events);
```

Ele nao pega o valor de **$atendente_paciente**, porque acontece isso e como eu poderia resolver?

Se eu coloco o valor de **$atendente_paciente** manualmente funciona

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT `id`, `start` ,`end` ,`title`,`ativo`,`atendente` FROM  `events` where (date(start) >= '$start' AND date(start) <= '$end' AND ativo='sim' and atendente='2'   ) ");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
```

Comment: esses dois código estão em um mesmo arquivo?

Comment: sim estão no mesmo arquivo

Comment: verifica com um `var_dump($atendente_paciente)` se a variável está trazendo o id

Comment: sim está trazendo  string(1) "2"

Answer (score 0):

Tentou passar o parametro da mesma forma que os outros parametros $start e $end ?

Assim:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT `id`, `start` ,`end` ,`title`,`ativo`,`atendente` FROM  `events` where (date(start) >= '$start' AND date(start) <= '$end' AND ativo='sim' and atendente='$atendente_paciente') ");
```

Comment: assim não deu certo também

Comment: Esta fazendo esta consulta no mesmo local do teste que retorna o resultado correto? 
"Atendente: ".$atendente_paciente;

Comment: Sim estão no mesmo local do teste e retorna com o var_dump($atendente_paciente) string(1) "2